# Gitlab - Is possible restore repositories files without DB backups?

Tags: restore, gitlab, bitnami, repository

I'm using bitnami gitlab stack on Vmware Vsphere ESXi 5.5, I have accidently deleted ibdata1 and mysql restarted. I don't have any backup, Only i can go to last Snapshop.

I need help to know is possible restore current repositories files with copy on last snapshot files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repositories are saved in `repos_path` defined in `gitlab.yml`. You can backup the repositories, and then reinstall GitLab from scratch.

GitLab has a [import script](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/tasks/gitlab/import.rake) to import existing repositories to GitLab. You can run the script, to get the projects recreated. Since you deleted the database, all existing events, comments, issues are lost!

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, this work for me, i used this command in gitlab installation directory: bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production - all projects imported but not users, how about import users? I try to add a user in admin area but show error "Username already exists"

Comment: Importing the users is not possible. How should it, because this data is stored in the database. Check where the repos a located now. I think of following problem. Consider the user `foo`. Then there would be a folder `repositories/foo`. If that folder already exist, it might be a problem while creating a new user. I propose moving all repos to the administrator namespace, import them to GitLab, recreate all users and then move the projects to the target namespace.

Comment: I removed users directories (namespaces) from repositories, but not allowed to create users, finally i created users with insert option from phpmyadmin in gitlab users table so users added now and show users in admin area. thanks